# How to show cross sell products into product.info.details in Magento 2

Tags: xml, view, product, magento2

I'm trying to show cross sell products into a product.info.details tab

Here's interested part of my code in catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="crosssell.tab" as="crossselltab" group="detailed_info" >
    <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cross sell</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

But it doesn't show me anything.

---

## Solved

Solved with this code:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="crosssell.tab" as="crossselltab" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
           <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cross sell</argument>
           <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
        </arguments>
     </block>
```

Comment: Please post your solution in an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="crosssell.tab" as="crossselltab" group="detailed_info" >
    <arguments>
       <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cross sell</argument>
       <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
    </arguments>
 </block>
```